# Jq that are not working corectly on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe someone see and can answer where is a problem why on IE8 not working alert @ first line 'lov_Dg2Id_D_1' but on next 'lov_Dg2Id_D_2' all is ok.

```
var SecondDiagnosis=$( "span[id^='lov_Dg2Id_D_']" );
var SpanBlock2=SecondDiagnosis.find('a');
var eventH2=SpanBlock2.attr( "onclick" );
//SpanBlock2.attr("onclick", "DgIdOnClick(document.getElementById('MovementNumber_D_'+parentElement.getAttribute('id').substring(12)).id,2);"+eventH2);
SpanBlock2.attr("onclick", "alert('HI!');"+eventH2);
```

Mabe are some other ways how can add a onclick event ?

Thanks Helpfull and Correct Answers guiranteed ;)

Comment: If you're using jQuery why aren't you adding a click handler with the `.click()` or `.on()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn about the library you are using.

You do not use attr to set events! jQuery has methods like [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) for that.

```
SpanBlock2.on("click", function() { alert('HI!'); });
```

You will not need to copy/call the original event, it will still be there.

If you want to change the order, you will need to bind the events

```
$("button").each( 
    function() {
       var btn = $(this);
        var oldClick = btn[0].onclick;
        btn.on("click", function(){ alert("a"); });
        if(oldClick) {
            btn[0].onclick = null;    
            btn.on("click", oldClick);
        }
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7K9pU/

Comment: In this case alert is after base events :( the example  what I described above  alert are first

Comment: Presumably the author is here asking questions in order to understand jQuery better. Perhaps some grace would be nice ;)

Comment: @Speakwithsystem just posted some code to make the inline event come after the newly added one.

Comment: Thanks this is working only when closing the main event on log are error :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
SpanBlock2.attr("onclick", "alert('HI!');"+eventH2);
```

to this:

```
var SecondDiagnosis=$( "span[id^='lov_Dg2Id_D_']" );
var SpanBlock2=SecondDiagnosis.find('a');

SpanBlock2.on("click", function(){
   // all your stuff you want on click of it.
});
```

Comment: Dier Jai ! 

JQ is not my best side can you please modify all 4 lines what is posted  on base question 

Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Speakwithsystem so you want to have an alert too.

Comment: I did not understand your example of how to modify the code for it to work correctly. Can you change the first post code? 
Thank you, I appreciate it;)